# Uploading apps to Google Playstore

Tags: android, google-play

I am a newbie and have just created an Android app to upload into the PlayStore.

I have followed instructions from [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en).

But I have few questions:
Currently I am using my phone to test the app, but can I assume it will work as seamlessly on other phones of different brands as they may have different UIs?

After I upload the apps, do I know who have installed my app like email ID so that I could send them emails regarding new apps in the future or updates available in PlayStore or I must depend on Google Playstore notifications for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Regarding app behavior on different hardware, do remember different Android Hardware Companies have optimized and customized android Operating system with respect to their hardware, so naturally it will behave different to some aspect.

2- Now who has installed your app, if it was a paid app, then you can get the email addresses from your merchant account order details.

If it was a free app, then the best you can do is put up notes in your old app description, and on your website if you have one.

3- Regarding update in android app, you can avail this feature programmatically and tutorialz are available over the internet as well. [Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9ryE6GwhmA)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just assume that it will work fine on all phones as phones and tablets come with different screen sizes, density and resolutions and layouts vary accordingly. Least you can do is try testing on differnt emulators if possible (in case you dont have other devices). There are sites where you can pay and get online devices to test.

For your other answer, you cannot directly get the email ids of others as it is against Google Privacy policy. But, you can integrate Google Analytics engine to get most of the infrmation about the user (which phone it is insatlled, which country, when is he using your app, how many people using your app at any time). For email id, you anyway have a gmail id for you app upload. You can request you app user to send you mail with feedbacks and problems. This you can include in the description field

Answer (score 1):

I have also just recently launched my first app, about 2 weeks ago.

1. **Not all phones will scale to the same size**, as there are different screen densities and height/width ratios. You can however get the height/width of the device, and scale the sizes of the things in your UI based on that.

   [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions) has a good example of getting the dimensions of the Android device.

   In the Eclipse IDE, you can also **use the emulator to test out different Android devices** that have different screen sizes, amounts of density pixels, have different Android versions, etc.
2. Google Play Developer only gives very basic statistics, like amounts of people who downloaded it, **but not actually who downloaded it**. I have heard that putting something like Google Analytics can give you more information, that is more up to date/accurate, but I'm not sure if it actually gives contact info.
3. Also, I released a few updates for my app, and I'm pretty sure Google Play sends notifications to update the app on the user's device, as **most of my users have updated within a couple of days of the new release**.